# Linking error with Qthreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Hey I am trying to do this basic program with Qthread. I have linking error and dont know how to resolve it. 
Inside the main method I call operate and it gives me this error:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes
>   Symbol ""public: void __thiscall Controller::operate(void)"
>   (?operate@Controller@@QAEXXZ)" in Funktion "_main".

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>


class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork() {
        QString result;

        for(int i= 0; i<10;i++){

           qDebug() << i <<endl;
           this->thread()->sleep(2);
        }

        emit resultReady(result);
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &result);
};



class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
    public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &);
    signals:
    void operate();
    void display(){
        qDebug() << "DISPLAYING";

        };
    };




 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Controller *c;

    c->operate();

   for(int i= 0; i<10;i++){

    c->display();
    a.thread()->sleep(1);

     }


      return a.exec();
   }
```

Do you have any idea what it could be?

Comment: where is your implementation for void operate() ?

Comment: @Brett-MichaelGreen its a signal that goes to doWork

Comment: This {} was missing operate(){} in declaration

Comment: signals should not have an implementation. they should only be declared.

Comment: I see with curly brackets it is not considered signal but method

Comment: btw: `Controller *c; c->operate();` will operate on unintialized memory. This will cause you problems when you get this running.

Comment: @Hayt what shoud I do instead? I am new to C++, Qt,

Comment: best would be to learn one thing first and the other later. Multithreaded Qt is quite something if you are new to this. Try familiarize yourself with c++ first, and when you think you grasp the concepts get into Qt.

Comment: @Hayt I though I have grasp somthing already...
This doesnt work:   Controller  *c = new Controller();

Comment: when this does not work then something else is wrong somewhere. I cannot tell you more there due to missing information here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't emit a signal by calling it like a function. This will try to call an implementation of the `operate()` which there is not.

To emit a signal use

```
emit c->operate(); //does not work with qt4. use implementation below
```

while this works Qt suggest to only emit signals from inside a class though. So you should have a function inside the class call the signal like

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
//...
    void startWork() { emit operate(); }
//...
};
```

Comment: @hereIam does it "compile" or "work"? Which Qt version are you using. On older Qt versions you can only emit the signal from inside the class. I added that to the answer.

Comment: did you replace `c->operate();` with `emit c->operate();`?

Comment: yes, also tried your trick void startWork() { emit operate(); }, doesnt work

Comment: is it the same linker error or this time with `display`? btw. you never use display like a signal but as a normal function call. Signals are not meant for this. Maybe you should have a read at this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals

Comment: I have that example from official pages:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

Comment: yeah `operate()` has no `{}` on there and the `main` you implemented was not in the example. When you want to "emit" a signal you call it with `emit`. Also your `display` should have no implementation and you should also call this one with "emit". If you want to make `display` a method write `public:` before it so you stop the signal declarations.

Comment: Is it the same linker error or do you get a different one?